# How to use Vanilla JS file with Express & Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, single-page-application

Hello I am Still learing Express and Node js I want to create a single page application with routes which i have done altho the vanilla javascript file is not working when i use express

### Express Code

```
import workout from "./views/workout.js";
import nutrition from "./views/nutrition.js";
import settings from "./views/settings.js";
import registration from "./views/registration.js";

const navigateTo = url => {
    history.pushState(null , null , url);
    router();
};

const router = async () =>{
    const routes = [
        {path: "/", view: Dashboard},
        {path: "/workout", view: workout},
        {path: "/nutrition", view: nutrition},
        {path: "/settings", view: settings},
        {path: "/registration", view: registration}
    ];

    // Test each route
    const potentialMatches = routes.map(route =>{
        return{
            route: route,
            isMatch: location.pathname === route.path
        }
    });

    let match = potentialMatches.find(potentialMatch => potentialMatch.isMatch);

    if(!match){
        match ={
            route: routes[0],
            isMatch: true
        }
    }
    const view = new match.route.view()

    document.querySelector("#app").innerHTML = await view.getHtml();
    

    console.log(match.route.view());
};
window.addEventListener("popstate", router);
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>{
    
    document.body.addEventListener('click', e=>{
        if (e.target.matches("[data-link]")) {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigateTo(e.target.href);
        }
    });

    router();
});
```

### Server Code

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();

app.use('/static' ,express.static(path.resolve(__dirname,"static")));



app.get("/*" , (req,res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,"index.html"));
    
});


app.get("/*" , (req,res)=> {
    
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, () => console.log('Server Running....'));
```

### Index.html file Calling js file

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Boxicons -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.1/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <!-- My CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/index.css">
    <script type="module" src="static/index.js"></script>
    <script  async src="static/nav.js"></script>
```

### Explanation

I want the regular javascript file to run it is not working i moved it to the static directory but i just get this issue Uncaught

**TypeError: workout_container is null
 http://localhost:8080/static/nav.js:19**

None of the buttons are working only a regular console.log works but the other pages functions and event listners arent working please help

Thank you